# Is 'such that' a conjunction in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

I read this sentence on [a webpage](https://interactioninstitute.org/endorsements/this-is-active-learning-such-that-you-gain-real-time-skills-in-facilitating-racial-justice-conversations/).

> This is active learning **such that** you gain real-time skills in
> facilitating racial justice conversations.

Is 'such that' a conjunction which has the same meaning as 'so that' in this sentence?

Comment: Yes: "that" is a subordinator. Such" is an adjective, here with a following content (_that_) clause, and together they are complement of "active learning". But "so that" is different: if substituted for "such that" in your example it would have a resultative meaning. Note that "that" is here obligatory in "such that", but omissible in "so that".

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *This is active learning* [*such that you gain real-time skills in*
> *facilitating racial justice conversations*].

Yes: "that" is a subordinator (your conjunction).

"Such" is an adjective, here with a following content (*that*) clause, and together they form a phrase that is complement of "active learning".

Replacing "such that" with "so that" gives a clause that is grammatically different as well as being semantically different, i.e. it would be an adjunct with a resultative interpretation.

Note that "that" is obligatory in "such that", but omissible in "so that".